# Firebase Authentication returns NULL for getCurrentUser()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When my Android app starts I check if the user is logged in and proceed. Later on I expect this line to always returns me the user object:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
```

That normally works but sometimes it returns `null`. Why is this? Is this normal? And how to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) is clear that it will return the currently logged in user, or null if there is none.  If you're getting null here, that means no user is logged in.

If you can clearly demonstrate that it returns null when there is *definitely* a user logged in, that is a bug.  Though I will say that this problem has never come up before, and it would massively break many applications if there was a bug here.

Consider [adding an AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)) to better understand when a user is logged in or not.  Please [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) to better understand the edge cases where a user may be present, but not yet fully authenticated and available to the SDK.  Using an AuthStateListener correctly deals with these cases.

Comment: Note: This is not happening on my device but on some of the devices in my beta program. It looks like it is happening a lot when the app wakes up. Could it be that Firebase needs a moment to initialize and I access the method before it is fully initialized? But I shouldn't be the only one with that problem. It's strange.

Comment: Perhaps.  The user's token may need a refresh after an hour, as well.  That's why you should be using an AuthStateListener to know for sure when the user is logged in and a User object is available.

Comment: Definitely also read the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: I just read in that doc file: *getCurrentUser might also return null because the auth object has not finished initializing*. Could you add that to your answer please.

Comment: I'll add a link to the documentation, because that can change over time, and should be the definitive source of information.

Comment: I think that `getCurrentUser()` is meant to wait for the initialization these days, which is why the sample in the docs was changed to no longer use `onAuthStateChanged`. The latter would be my suggestion: register a listener for auth state changes.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen getCurrentUser() can't wait, because that would make it a blocking API, and Firebase SDKs don't have any of those, by design.  In theory it could be async, but that would require it to return a Task that resolves with a User object.

Comment: I have an authStateListener, is there a way to keep the email authentication .onComplete() from firing until the auth object is finished initializing?